# how to write value in tags in JavaScript this throw error unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

I want to have value of element which has id `in1` but this throw an error of type unexpected identifier. Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
onput.innerHTML = "<li>document.getElementById("in1").value</li>";
```

Comment: what is `onput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this,

```
onput.innerHTML = "<li>" + document.getElementById("in1").value + "</li>";
```

Comment: thanks brother for helping me i was very helpless and depressed but you resolve my problem  you are very good thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `<l1>` tags. Also the `getElementById` function cannot be inside a string.
EX:

```js
onput.innerHTML = document.getElementById("in1").value;
```